# Create kind of index in Pyspark with window and row_number

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i'm trying to create a index in a dataframe with pyspark, windown and row_number function.

For example:

**Original dataframe**

Obs: the data are random

| Coldata |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
| F |
| G |
| H |
| I |

**Expected Dataframe:**

| Coldata | index |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 2 |
| F | 2 |
| G | 3 |
| H | 3 |
| I | 3 |

My Code in moment is:

```
w = Window.orderBy("Coldata")
df_expected= df.withColumn("index",  row_number().over(w))
```

But this returns 1,2,3,4,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate `(row_number + 2) / 3` and cast to integer:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'index',
    ((F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('Coldata')) + 2) / 3).cast('int')
)

df2.show()
+-------+-----+
|colData|index|
+-------+-----+
|      A|    1|
|      B|    1|
|      C|    1|
|      D|    2|
|      E|    2|
|      F|    2|
|      G|    3|
|      H|    3|
|      I|    3|
+-------+-----+
```